# What is the difference between applying of `operator new(std::size_t);` and `new-expression`?

Tags: c++

I would like to understand all differences between `operator new(std::size_t)` and `new-expression`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

using std::cout;

struct A
{
    int a;
    char b;
    A(){ cout << "A\n"; a = 5; b = 'a'; } 
    ~A(){ cout << "~A\n"; }
};

A *a = (A*)operator new(sizeof(A)); //allocates 8 bytes and return void*
A *b = new A(); //allocates 8 bytes, invoke a default constructor and return A*
```

Could you provide all differences between them? Do they work in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new` expression *invokes* the allocation function `operator new`. The allocation function obtains memory, and the `new` expression converts memory into objects (by constructing them).

So the following code:

```
T * p = new T(1, true, 'x');
delete p;
```

Is equivalent to the following sequence of operations:

```
void * addr = operator new(sizeof(T));   // allocation

T * p = new (addr) T(1, true, 'x');      // construction

p->~T();                                 // destruction

operator delete(addr);                   // deallocation
```

Please note that you *always* need a `new` expression to create objects (i.e. call constructors) -- constructors have no name and cannot be called directly. In this case, we use the default placement-new expression, which does nothing but create the object, unlike the non-placement form, which does both memory allocation and object construction.

Comment: Do c++spec said that?

Comment: @St.Antario: Sort of, yes. There are details, of course, e.g. `new T` is atomic with respect to exceptions in both the allocation function and the `T` constructor...

Comment: Could you improve your question to provide a reference?

Comment: @St.Antario: Unary expressions, clause 5...

Comment: @St.Antario It's the entire section 5.3.4 [expr.new]. (and 5.3.5 for `delete`)

Comment: @KerrekSB Understandable, greatest!

Answer (score 2):

The `new-expression` allocates the memory needed **and** calls the  respective constructor (given the arguments) for the newly allocated object.

The `new(std::size_t) operator` just allocates the memory.

Read more at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/